# Google Pub/Sub pull Error parsing subscription resource is not specified

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I Using the Google Console to set up Pub/Sub and implemented asynchronous pull to get the message from the subscription. This is the command line with the error message saying Error paring the subscription. With the error message, how can I find the project info and set the attribute [property] correctly?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull GmailSub
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.pubsub.subscriptions.pull) Error parsing
>   [subscription]. The [subscription] resource is not properly specified.
>
> Failed to find attribute [project]. The attribute can be set in the following ways: - Set the property `[core/project]` or provide the flag `[--project]` on the command line

Answer (score 7):

The project ID would be the ID of the project in which you created the subscription. If you go to the [Cloud Console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/home/dashboard), you can see the project ID listed in the "Project Info" box. If you are using the same project for everything, can set the default project for the gcloud tool:

> gcloud config set project <project ID>

Comment: This helps actually.